# How to conditionally apply x-ua meta tag only to ie10 and below?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, meta-tags, ie8-compatibility-mode, x-ua-compatible

I have a situation where the following x-ua code is added to the header

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7" />
```

and it works well in IE versions 10 and below. **But it makes some functionalities not working in IE11**.

Functionalities will work fine in IE11 if the meta tag is removed, but now **i'm not in a position to remove the meta tag completely as my application has to support IE9+ versions** and the removal will make functionalities not to work in IE10

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<!--[if IE 9]>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<![endif]-->
```

Note: IE10 doesn't support conditional comments https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/compatibility/hh801214(v=vs.85)